# Javafx - slow declaration/launch the piece of code (values) against rest

Tags: java, javafx

Hello I have a problem with this piece of code, I don't understand why launchData even when it is loaded and defined earlier as declaration of ErrorHandler is launched after ErrorHandler. See Output and code.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {       
    public ErrorHandler errorHandler;

    @FXML
    public VBox bottomVbox;

 public void launchData() {
       // DragResizer.makeResizable(sqlTabPane);
       // DragResizer.makeResizable(csvTabPane);
      //  DragResizer.makeResizable(tableTabPane);

      Main.getPrimaryStage().widthProperty().addListener((arg,oldVal,newVal) -> {
            HBox.setPrefWidth((Double) newVal);
            upperPanelHBox.setPrefWidth((Double) newVal);
            bottomVbox.setPrefWidth((Double) newVal);
            System.out.println("AFTER RUNNING LAUNCH: " + bottomVbox.getPrefWidth());
        });

  @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        launchData();
        errorHandler = new ErrorHandler(bottomVbox);
...
}
```

Class ErrorHandler:

```
public class ErrorHandler {
   TextArea textArea;
    public ErrorHandler(VBox vBox) {
   //     vBox.getChildren().a
        System.out.println("VBOX WIDTH AFTER IMPLEMENTING ERRORHANLDER: " + vBox.getPrefWidth());
...
}
```

OUTPUT:

- VBOX WIDTH AFTER IMPLEMENTING ERRORHANLDER: -1.0
- AFTER RUNNING LAUNCH: 1042.0

Any Idea why it is loaded this way ? 
I expected:
 - VBOX WIDTH AFTER IMPLEMENTING ERRORHANLDER: 1042.0
 - AFTER RUNNING LAUNCH: 1042.0

Comment: Your "AFTER RUNNING LAUNCH..." print statement is invoked inside a _listener_; specifically, a listener that is listening to the width of the primary stage. It will only be called when the stage changes width. This happens for the first time _after_ the stage has been shown which is _after_ the `initialize` method has been invoked.

Comment: Yes, you are right... any idea when I call here (out of listener of primary stage) Main.getPrimaryStage.getScene() returns me null? 

I checked if primary stage is same get from controller and created in Main, it is... but scene in Main SCENE: javafx.scene.Scene@44b60533
and from Controller it is NULL, I need width of scene to set it to vbox

Comment: If you're calling that inside `launchData`, which is called inside `initialize`, then you get `null` because the scene hasn't been set on the stage yet. The `initialize` method is invoked _during a call to `FXMLLoader.load`_. You do this before the scene is set.

Comment: So how would you send width and height, or Scene to Controller? 
    private Scene mainScene = Main.getPrimaryStage().getScene();
I tried this in controller class ...  and Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
I get imidiatelly after launch app.

Comment: `VBox` should automatically fill the width of its parent node.